Intermittent error with resource loading in ASP.NET MVC application, ERR_HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED
I have an ASP.NET MVC (on .NET Framework) application that loads resources such as .js files using the following command:
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Sometimes, I encounter the following error:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED

This issue seems to occur randomly.
I provided the example with jQuery, but the problem could happen with any other bundle, such as Summernote.
I should mention that the resources are hosted locally, not on a CDN or any other external source.
If you have any ideas or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. The most challenging part is that this issue is so unpredictable...
Thank you in advance for your help.
I tried to disable HTTP/2 on my IIS server but without success. In any case, this wouldn’t be an ideal solution.
Best regards

Have you tried using FireFox? (because it's the only browser that isn't Chromium-based). Also if FireFox returns the same error, it might be worth trying a non-browser based tool to query the HTTP endpint like CURL or PowerShell.

You need more information to analyze your problem, check the IIS logs for any errors or warnings related to the bundles being served. The logs might give you more insights into what causes the ERR_HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED error.
